# No logging and repository root has appender but Logger has no appender

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, xunit

I'm sure I'm missing something basic.  I'm trying to enable log4net logging as part of an XUnit integration test, but no log file is getting written to disk.

I've tried specifying the log configuration using both using a config file and programmatically:

**Config file:**

```
 <log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>
  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="mylog.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

**Programatically**

```
    private void ConfigureAppender()
    {
        var layout = new PatternLayout("%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline");
        var appender = new RollingFileAppender {Name = "file", File = "c:\\temp\\mylog.log", AppendToFile = true, RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size, MaxSizeRollBackups = 5, MaximumFileSize = "10MB", StaticLogFileName = true, Layout = layout};
        var repository = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;
        repository.Root.AddAppender(appender);
        repository.Root.Level = Level.Info;
        repository.Configured = true;
        repository.RaiseConfigurationChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

I then get the logger, as early in the program execution as possible, using something like this (I've tried `[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]` as well):

```
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo("log4net.config");
        if (!fileInfo.Exists) throw new Exception();
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(fileInfo);
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        log.Fatal("This is a test");
```

No logs either way.  Whether I define the logging via config or programmatically, I see the screenshot at bottom when I inspect the log object.  Note the following:

1. The level settings have been picked up from the config definition.
2. The repository root has the two appenders as defined in the config definition.
3. The Logger instance itself has no appenders.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

[image]

**EDIT:**
This is what I missed, as determined from Z.R.T.'s answer:

- I needed a `logger` element in the log4net.config/app.config.
- I needed to reference the logger by name, e.g. `LogManager.GetLogger("IntegrationLogger");`.

Once I added these two things, log4net started working. The only downside is that all the logs are marked with "IntegrationLogger" instead of the class in which the log is generated, but this at least got the logging started.

Comment: Have you tried [enabling log4net debug mode](https://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/)

Comment: I have not - great tip.  The day's getting late, so I'll check this out first thing tomorrow.

Comment: I actually just tried it - copied the content verbatim from the link you provided into my app.config, moved the log4net content into the app.config, and updated the FileInfo instance to use the app.config, ran it and ... nada.  No mylog.log, and no log4net.txt.  :(  Still a good suggestion tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**log4net.config** - set copy if newer or copy always

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="SomeRollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="..\\logs\\loginfo.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <logger name="SomeLogger">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="SomeRollingLogFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

**Log.cs**

```
public class Log
{
    private static readonly ILog someLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("SomeLogger");
    static Log()
    {
        if (!UnitTestDetector.IsRunningFromNUnit)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
        }
        else
        {
            var testDir = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory;
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(testDir,"log4net.config")));
        }
    }

    public static void Info(string msg)
    {
        someLogger.Info(msg);
    }
}

static class UnitTestDetector
{
    static UnitTestDetector()
    {
        foreach (Assembly assem in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            if (assem.FullName.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("nunit.framework"))
            {
                IsRunningFromNUnit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool IsRunningFromNUnit { get; } = false;
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
[TestFixture]
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Log.Info("test");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Log.Info("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, I see what I missed now.  Will update my question with the details.  Thanks!